# How to get an Array value inside an object in an array Php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array below at the last code part. To get ["db"] and ["size"] object in array through a loop I use

```
<?php 
foreach ($result->cpanelresult->data as $value){  
<b>DB Name:</b> <?php echo $value->db; ?> | <b>Size:</b> <?php echo $value->size; ?>
} 
?>
```

It works as expected, but the problem is I am trying to access user string in userlist array but its giving me difficulty, I tried this

```
<?php echo $value->userlist->user; ?>
```

It did not work, I get error **Trying to get property 'user' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\auth\ajax.php on line 582** because userlist is an Array. Please what am I doing wrong.

```
object(stdClass)#65 (1) { 
["cpanelresult"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (7) { 
["preevent"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { 
["result"]=> int(1) 
} 
["module"]=> string(7) "MysqlFE" 
["data"]=> array(29) { 

[0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (5) { 
["db"]=> string(20) "saska_example" 
["size"]=> string(4) "8192" 
["userlist"]=> array(1) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { 
["user"]=> string(20) "saska_example" 
["db"]=> string(20) "saska_example" 
} 
} 
["usercount"]=> int(1) 
["sizemeg"]=> string(4) "0.01" 
} 

[1]=> object(stdClass)#7 (5) { 
["size"]=> string(4) "8192" 
["userlist"]=> array(1) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) { 
["db"]=> string(13) "saska_exampleone" 
["user"]=> string(13) "saska_exampleone" 
} 
} 
["usercount"]=> int(1) 
["sizemeg"]=> string(4) "0.01" 
["db"]=> string(13) "saska_exampleone" 
}  

[2]=> object(stdClass)#10 (5) { 
["userlist"]=> array(1) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#9 (2) { 
["db"]=> string(16) "saska_exampletwo" 
["user"]=> string(16) "saska_exampletwo" 
} 
} 
["size"]=> string(4) "8192" 
["usercount"]=> int(1) 
["sizemeg"]=> string(4) "0.01" 
["db"]=> string(16) "saska_exampletwo" 
}

[3]=> object(stdClass)#11 (5) { 
["db"]=> string(13) "saska_demo" 
["sizemeg"]=> string(4) "5.63" 
["size"]=> string(7) "5906432" 
["userlist"]=> array(1) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#12 (2) { 
["user"]=> string(13) "saska_root" 
["db"]=> string(13) "saska_demo" 
} 
} 
["usercount"]=> int(1) 
} 

["event"]=> object(stdClass)#63 (1) { 
["result"]=> int(1) 
} 
["func"]=> string(7) "listdbs" 
["apiversion"]=> int(2) 
["postevent"]=> object(stdClass)#64 (1) { 
["result"]=> int(1) 
}
```

Comment: `<?php echo $value->userlist[0]->user; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

So I got the answer from u_mulder in the comment section as

```
<?php echo $value->userlist[0]->user; ?>
```